# Computing simplicial homology of the 2-sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplex

I've been essentially taking a crash course in simplicial homology over the past 2 days. I would like to compute the homology groups $H_{k}$ of the 2-sphere. I have a somewhat rigorous argument given below and I'd love if someone could tell me if this argument is sound.

We can triangulate the 2-sphere using the shell of a $3$-simplex, and let's call this $T$ and its vertices $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. We know that $H_{k}(S^{2}) \cong H_{k}(T)$. We take a look at the chain complex
$$ \cdots \xrightarrow{\partial_{4}}  0 \xrightarrow{\partial_{3}} C_{2}(T) \xrightarrow{\partial_{2}} C_{1}(T) \xrightarrow{\partial_{1}} C_{0}(T) \xrightarrow{\partial_{1}} 0. $$
We know that $T$ is path connected and so $H_{0}(T) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Obviously, $\text{im} (\partial_{3}) = 0$ and the only generator for $\ker (\partial_{2})$ is $-bcd+acd-abd+abc$. So, we get $H_{2}(T) = \ker (\partial_{2})/\text{im} (\partial_{3}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Now, I would like to get that $H_{1}(T) = 0$. I checked where the basis elements of $C_{2}(T)$ and $C_{1}(T)$ are sent through $\partial_{2}$ and $\partial_{1}$ respectively and found that $\text{rank} \ \text{im}(\partial_{2}) = \text{rank} \ker (\partial_{1}) = 3$, and using the fact that $\text{im} (\partial_{2}) \subset \ker(\partial_{1})$ we get that $\text{rank} \ H_{1}(T) = 0$ and we're done.

Something that bothers me about the way I did this is that I resorted to using a fair amount of linear algebra to show that $H_{1}(T) = 0$. I imagine that chasing elements would be pretty tedious if this proof was done for the $n$-sphere, which is what I'll do next. Is there a nice result or slick way to go about showing $H_{1}(T) = 0$ (less looking at individual elements)? Thanks!

Comment: Linear algebra is the heart and soul of homology calculations. One can certainly learn to do linear algebra calculations more efficiently, but if a homology calculation starts like this one from a raw description of the simplicial complex, and then has no linear algebra, then something is probably wrong.

Comment: I am not sure that you can conclude $H_1(T)=0$ from $\operatorname{rk}(\operatorname{im}(\partial_2))= \operatorname{rk}(\operatorname{ker}(\partial_1))=3$ and $\operatorname{im}(\partial_2)\subseteq \operatorname{ker}(\partial_1)$. Consider for instance the chain complex $\mathbb{Z}^3\xrightarrow{\partial_2} \mathbb{Z}^3\rightarrow 0$ with $\partial_2$ multiplication by $3$ in each component. While $\operatorname{rk}(\operatorname{im}(\partial_2))= \operatorname{rk}((3\mathbb{Z})^3)=3$, the first homology group is non-zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The truth is, it is very rare to compute the homology of a space "explicitly" like this. This may work for small, finite examples, but as soon as you have a big space this becomes awful.

Instead, we have many tools (theorems) at our disposal to compute the homology of a space. One of them is the Mayer–Vietoris theorem. It roughly says that if your space $X$ can be decomposed as the union of two open subsets $U$, $V$, and such that you know the homologies $H_*(U)$, $H_*(V)$, and $H_*(U \cap V)$, and if you know how they are related to one another under inclusion, then you can know the homology of $X$.

For the sphere, the standard way to do this is to view $S^n$ as the union of the two hemispheres $U$ and $V$. Then $U$ and $V$ are both contractible (hence $H_*(U)$ and $H_*(V)$ vanish in positive degree), and $U \cap V = S^{n-1}$. So using induction, you find the homology of $S^n$, just knowing the homology of $S^0$, which is very easy.

But it's a good exercise to try and compute the homology "explicitly" as you did. This way, when you learn about the powerful theorems, you can appreciate how much effort they save you.

---

However, don't be surprised that you had to resort to a lot of linear algebra. As abstract as things become, in the end, we're just computing kernels and images... We can't escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Because your triangulation consists explicitly of the shell of a 3-simplex, you ought to be able to argue directly that each element of a basis 2-cycle in that shell is also a 2-face, and obtain the rank image equality immediately. This argument should generalize to show that $H_{n-2}(T)=0$ in n dimensions.